# Entity Framework Cascade not deleting children but setting null

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

These are my 2 models:

```
public class SystemMessage
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string AdministratorId { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public IList<SystemMessageAttachment> SystemMessageAttachment { get; } = new List<SystemMessageAttachment>();
}

public class SystemMessageAttachment
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string MIMEType { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string SystemMessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemMessage SystemMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

In the DbContext, under the onModelCreating function, I have this relationship set:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemMessageAttachment>()
            .HasOne(b => b.SystemMessage)
            .WithMany(b=>b.SystemMessageAttachment)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

However, when I delete a System Message, its child which is the attachment isnt deleted? The SystemMessageId is only set to NULL.

Is there anything I'm missing? Why wont cascade work here?

EDIT:
This is how I delete the system message:

```
public bool Delete(string Id)
{
    try
    {
        var a = Get(Id);
        if (a == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        dbContext.SystemMessage.Remove(a);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError(e, "Failed to delete System Message" + " - " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you deleting your `Message`?

Comment: you can verify if the deletion cascading is applied correctly to the database. If not, something wrong with the model configuration. As said by documentation about `DeleteBehavior.Cascade`, it seems like to cascade deletion only ***in-memory*** that applies on tracked entities only. That's kind of a weird design (or documented) because we know for sure that there is something like `on delete cascade` which is implemented on the database engine side. `EFCore` does have a way to configure that thing. As a trial, can you make `SystemMessageId` as `required` to see how it's handling?

Comment: BTW, if you just added `OnDelete` configuration after your first db migration, you need to add a new migration for that configuration change and try updating the target database. If any error occurs, you may need to fix it by manual scripts.

Comment: Odd, because I just tested it quickly, and for me the SystemMessageAttachments got deleted when I invoked DbSet<>.Remove() with a SystemMessage instance. So these models and configuration seem insufficient to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ESG I updated the question with my delete function.

Comment: @KingKing this is the first dbmigration. I checked the database and SystemMessage is being deleted. But the SystemMessageId field in SystemMessageAttachment is set to null.

Comment: @Leaky , this is the first time it happened for me as well. The other cascades seem to work properly

Comment: I think I managed to solve it. The application handling the System Message needed its dbcontext updated. I think that was the issue.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. In the end it's the database that should have a FK constraint with cascaded delete. I wouldn't mind if you put that in a self-answer, because others also run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a cascade delete you have to include the children:

```
var removingRow=_context.Set<SystemMessage>()
.Include(x=> x.SystemMessageAttachment)
.Where(x => x.Id ==id)
.FirstOrDefault();

if(removingRow != null)
{
_context.Remove(removingRow);
_context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I manually set it like this, wouldnt it defeat the purpose of asking my db to handle the cascade for me?

Comment: "If you want to use a cascade delete you have to include the children" - nope, `cascade delete` entirely is managed by the database, not by EF. Therefore, no need to fetch the children with `Include`.